# predefined function is undefined during onpress

Tags: react-native

I am having problem during onPress it will raised an error undefined function...etc.

can some one help me please what is wrong with my code. why I can not call that _deletetRecord function.

Thank you in advance.

```
_deleteRecord = (id) => {

        this.props.deleteRecord(id);
    }; 

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation}) =>{
return{
       headerRight: (
                <IconIonicons
                    color="white"
                    name="md-trash"
                    size={24}
                    onPress={() =>this._deleteRecord(params.id)}
                    style={{color: '#ffffff', marginRight: 15}}
                />

            ),
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `onPress={() =>this._deleteRecord(params.id)}` to `onPress={this._deleteRecord(params.id).bind(this)}`